# JTable java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to add a new row to the empty `JTable`

Here is my code:

```
Object columnNamesPax[] = {"#","Name","Surname","Sex","Age","Class"};
Object[][] data = new Object[5][columnNamesPax.length];

JTable tablePax = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNamesPax));

DefaultTableModel defaultModel = (DefaultTableModel) tablePax.getModel();
System.out.println(tablePax.getColumnCount());
defaultModel.addRow(new Object[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6"});
```

Console output:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 6
>
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range

I don't understand why there is IndexOutOfBoundsException, if the number of columns is 6.

Comment: Your best bet here is to show us your code. We don't want to see all of it, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, in other words,a [mcve] (please see the link).

Comment: Your code above does not show the error. For example, when I use the code above to create **my** [mcve], no such error occurs: [link to my mcve](http://pastebin.com/fPZ8GtUm). So **again** it is up to you to create and post ***your*** [mcve] so we can actually help you.

Comment: You accepted a non-answer, what is going on? Please explain whether or how you resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## NOT AN ANSWER

Your code above does not show the error. For example, when I use the code above to create **my** [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), no such error occurs:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Object columnNamesPax[] = { "#", "Name", "Surname", "Sex",
                        "Age", "Class" };
                Object[][] data = new Object[5][columnNamesPax.length];

                JTable tablePax = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data,
                        columnNamesPax));

                DefaultTableModel defaultModel = (DefaultTableModel) tablePax
                        .getModel();
                System.out.println(tablePax.getColumnCount());
                defaultModel.addRow(new Object[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" });

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(tablePax));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Your just posting uncompilable and unrunnable snippets of code just isn't cutting it as they don't contain enough information to allow us to see your error. Also, we don't want to see your complete code base and thus be swamped by a large amount of unrelated code, and so **again** it is up to you to create and post ***your*** [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) similar to my example above (please also see the link that I've provided), one that demonstrates your problem for us, which will hopefully allow us to actually help you.